# SearchBar method deprecated issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, io, ios5

I used this method but it's saying it is deprecated. Which method should I use instead of this method?

```
 -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
    {
        [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: What method is deprecated exactly? Did you read the doc for each one? There may be an indication on what method use. Also, what's with theses tags?

Comment: -(BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
    return YES;
}

Comment: Read the documentation of `UISearchDisplayDelegate`: `Important: UISearchDisplayDelegate is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that UISearchDisplayController is also deprecated.) To manage the presentation of a search bar and display search results in iOS 8 and later, instead use UISearchControllerDelegate.`

Answer (score 0):

**UISearchDisplayController class replaces from UISearchController class**

```
 - (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
 {
    // Your logic here
 }

 - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope
 {
  //[self updateSearchResultsForSearchController:searchController];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Document Says](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchdisplaycontroller?language=objc)

> UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that
>   UISearchDisplayDelegate is also deprecated.) To manage the
>   presentation of a search bar and display search results in iOS 8 and
>   later, instead use **UISearchController**.